# How to execute a php file from another php file

Tags: php

I have a php file and at the bottom I need to run another php file.

Code:

```
<?PHP
/*
code

execute another php file. Ex: \jobs\process.php
return 0;
?>
```

Comment: make a function, that takes whatever parameters, to return 0 ? require_once(your_file) or include(your_file)?

Comment: He might want to get its output. Eh... a good question is worth good answer.

Comment: If you want the output you could post to it...cURL is good for that.

Comment: Did you want the output from another file in to first file?

Comment: this is a php script with no functions. Just executing the file (from a cron job, for example) does some things. What I need is to execute a similar php script when this one is done.

Answer (score 3):

```
include("path/filename");
require("path/filename");

require_once("path/filename");

include_once("path/filename");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) / [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) it.

```
include("filename.php");
require("filename.php");
```

Or you can use

```
$output = shell_exec("php filename.php"); 
var_dump($output);
```

I recommend first solutions :)

Comment: does not work like that. This is a php script with no functions. Just executing the file (from a cron job, for example) does some things. What I need is to execute a similar php script when this one is done.

Comment: If you want to execute a php script when other one is done, you should use bash scripting.

Answer (score 0):

A php file is automatically executed when it is requested from the server.

So, you can execute it by [including](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [requiring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the file in your current file, like this:

```
<?php
.
.
include 'file to be executed';
.
.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply include a php file top of the file. 
 
    `include("filename.php");`